# Error_log doesn't work when PHP script is running via /user/bin/php

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron, centos

Well I have a cron that runs a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {1..10}; do
   /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/teste_sh.php v=$n &
done
```

But in this script teste_sh.php, If I do an error_log, it doesn't work.

Error_log of this folder is empty, but if I run http://localhost/teste_sh.php, error_log works fine!

Is there a way to make error_log work in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly clear on where your error log is, but, It's a permission issue. The CRON assumedly is a crontab on your user, not root.

I would place your user in the same group as your web server, often `www-data`.

Then the web server, and you when executing via CRON, will be in same group. Of course just need to make sure the directory /var/www/html is chowned to that group.

Add your user to web group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data myusername
```

And then chown the directory

```
sudo chown -R myusername:www-data /var/www/html
```

Might be worth taking a look for an answer on https://serverfault.com/